# CSS Background-size > 100% doesn't work Android Default Browser

Tags: css, android-browser, mobile-webkit

I've found a bug for the Android Default Browser. The Background-size property if a value is set bigger then 100% it won't work.

http://punkbit.com/tests/android_native_browser_bg_size_issue.html

On the previous example, I've set a body bacgrkound image that should be 175% but that's not working.

The prefixes are set and this was also tested for Chrome, Safari and works fine in the same mobile device S3 Mini.

Any suggestions ?

Having this meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" that I need for responsiveness, this won't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
background-size:cover
```

instead of 175%

Comment: Thanks  for looking! I actually need to have control over the percentage of the size image. I find that having the meta content="width=device-width" it won't work.